# Spark Yarn Cluster - java.lang.StackOverflowError error when number of hive columns are greater than 200

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to load csv file of 250 columns using Apache Spark into Hive external table and I am getting StackOverflow error.. It is working fine with 150 columns and more than that it is throwing Stackoverflow.. I am running this in yarn cluster mode..
diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError

I tried increasing the spark.executor.extraJavaOptions but no luck with it..

Can you please suggest any other jvm settings to be changed to increase the stack size for working with 250 columns..

Few more information on the question,

Below is detailed exception on the stackoverflow error.. I believe it is failing while trying to parse the Schema object(Array of StructFields of size 250).. 
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at

Is there any alternative way to specify schema for long list of struct fields?

Comment: Can you add your code?.. a stackoverflow sounds it that has to do with your code instead Spark memory options

Comment: I have added the exception I face.. Sorry unable to share my code here but the code is simple.. get dataframe from csv file and load it into hive table.. Schema Scala object i created is of size 250  which is array of structfields and it is throwing stackoverflow error while trying to parse that schema..